# How to release Application.Cells properly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote some code, but I can't release Application.Cells properly. Are there anyone can help me to release Excel.exe in Task manager?

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application app = null;
Excel.Workbooks books = null;
Excel.Workbook book = null;
Excel.Sheets sheets = null;

    for (int a = 0; a < dgrviRoute.RowCount; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < dgrviRoute.ColumnCount; b++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dgrviRoute.Rows[a];                                    
                DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[b];                                    
                var value = cell.Value;                                                                       
                app.Cells[a + 2, b + 1] = value;
                /*
                I still see the Excel.exe process in the Windows Task Managers’ 
                list of background processes.

                This strange phenomenon occurs because in the above code, 
                Iam not releasing any COM objects and we’re also “chaining” 
                object references by using app.Cells[a + 2, b + 1].
                */

                /*
                if (app.Cells[a + 2, b + 1] != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app.Cells[a + 2, b + 1]);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                */
            }                      
    }
```

I read some Tutorial at here [How to properly release Excel COM objects](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a long battle. I have tried everything for my apps. Did not work out. Using OpenXML is better for simple write functions. It does not invoke excel application just manipulates the excel file which is in XML format. For this particular situation you can use a process kill to dispose all the excel objects.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pro = ExcelProcess.GetExcelProcess(app);
pro.Kill();
```

Need to define ExcelProcess.GetExcelProcess method

```
public class ExcelProcess
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    public static System.Diagnostics.Process GetExcelProcess(oExcel.Application excelApp)
    {
        int id;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelApp.Hwnd, out id);
        return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id);
    }
}
```